# Image transform glitches

Tags: image-transforms

We're having trouble with images being transformed with glitches in them. What would you advise to debug behavior like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried both GD and Imagick? Just to see if it happens with both?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), try swapping to [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).  Also, make sure you're using a recent version of the [library](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) as well as the [PHP wrapper](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick) extension.